# Finding 70% Voltage Point

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, ac, gain, phasor

Let \$v_1\$ be the input AC voltage and \$v_2\$ be the output AC voltage such that gain \$\dfrac{v_2}{v_1} = \dfrac{A+jB}{D+jE}\$ where \$j = \sqrt{-1}\$. How should I find the 70% point (the point where the gain is reduced by a factor of \$\sqrt{2}\$)?

I was told that I must set \$D = E\$. In that case, \$\dfrac{v_2}{v_1} = \dfrac{A+jB}{D(1+j)}\$. The explaination I was given was: since \$|1+j| = \sqrt{2}\$, the ratio is decreased by a factor of \$\sqrt{2}\$.

But what I don't understand about this is that, initially when \$\dfrac{v_2}{v_1} = \dfrac{A+jB}{D+jE}\$, the magnitude is \$\dfrac{v_2}{v_1} = \dfrac{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{\sqrt{D^2+E^2}}\$. When \$\dfrac{v_2}{v_1} = \dfrac{A+jB}{D(1+j)}\$, the magnitude is \$\dfrac{v_2}{v_1} = \dfrac{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{D\sqrt{2}}\$. But $$\dfrac{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{\sqrt{D^2+E^2}} / \dfrac{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{D\sqrt{2}} = \dfrac{D\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{D^2+E^2}} \neq \sqrt{2}$$ Clearly the gain has not decreased by a factor of \$\sqrt{2}\$.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: it annoys me to refer sqrt(2) as %70

Comment: @muyustan Should it be 71%? \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 71\%\$

Comment: @Huisman I think it should not be referred as a percentage at all.  -3dB cutoff sounds good.

Comment: I apologise for the confusion. My professor referred to it as 70% point so I assumed that that's what it's commonly known as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## IN GENERAL the whole approach of setting \$D=E\$  is incorrect.

It fails e.g. in the quite obvious example of \$A=D\$ and \$B=E\$.

$$$$

### The approach is only valid when

- D is constant and E is variable (or vice versa)
- the variable can become very small or very big with respect to constant

$$$$

Let D be the constant and E the variable (think of E being frequency dependend).

Let E be originally very small

The magnitude of \$\dfrac{v_2}{v_1}\$ is

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{\sqrt{D^2+E^2}}$$

When \$E \ll D\$
 the magnitude becomes $$\dfrac{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{D}$$

Then, E increases such that \$E = D\$
 the magnitude becomes $$\dfrac{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{D\sqrt{2}}$$

Next, you should divide the new magnitude by the original magnitude (not the other way around as in the OP!!), so
 $$\dfrac{NEW} {ORIGINAL} = \dfrac{ \dfrac{ \sqrt{A^2+B^2} }{ \sqrt{ D^2+{(E|_{E = D})}^2} }  }{ \dfrac{ \sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{\sqrt{D^2+{(E|_{E \ll D})}^2}} } = \dfrac{ \dfrac{ \sqrt{A^2+B^2} }{D\sqrt{2}}  }{ \dfrac{ \sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{D} } = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

## conclusion

- write out the transfer function
- for finding useful point (for e.g. bode diagram) find for both the numerator as well as the denominator:

  - the frequency for which the real part is significant larger than the imaginary part
  - the frequency for which the real part is equal to the imaginary part
  - the frequency for which the real part is significant smaller than the imaginary part
    e imaginary part

Answer (score 1):

> I was told that I must set \$D=E\$

No, because that would alter the magnitude of the input voltage \$v_1\$ and, unless the output magnitude were altered by the same amount then the ratio result would be wrong.

Stick with finding the magnitude of the input and output signals as seperate entities then make the division.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Suppose \$\dfrac{v_2}{v_1} = \dfrac{1}{1+j\omega RC}\$ where R, C is resistance and capacitance. How should I go about finding the \$\sqrt{2}\$ point?

Comment: Quite simply when \$\omega RC = 1\$ or \$F = \frac{1}{2\pi RC}\$

Comment: @Andyaka So, you do use D=E, where D=1 and E=
ωRC ? :)

Comment: @Huisman no, you would use \$\sqrt{\dfrac{A^2+B^2}{D^2+E^2}}\$ and equate to 0.7071 (or \$\dfrac{A^2+B^2}{D^2+E^2}\$ and equate to 0.5).